# Selenium fails to open new firefox binary with profile when FF is already open

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My app is using selenium to automate the browser - NOT for testing apps but to actually be part of the running app.

I'm trying to load the profile for FF in selenium but it doesn't work when I have a version of FF open. I'm trying to solve it with something like below.

```
        IEnumerable<int> pidsBefore = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox").Select(p => p.Id);

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(pathsToProfiles[0]);
        profile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.loadInBackground", false); // set preferences you need
        if (pidsBefore.Count() > 0)
        {
  //this next line is where I need to grab the currently open browser somehow - I know this wont work as it wont bring up the selenium webdriver plugin but ...
            driver = new FirefoxDriver((FirefoxBinary)Process.GetProcessById(pidsBefore.Last()), profile, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
        else
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), profile, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
              //this also fails below

              // driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
              // The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4xcr92nu.default-1373036135509\parent.lock' because it is being used by another process.
        }
        IEnumerable<int> pidsAfter = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox").Select(p => p.Id);
        IEnumerable<int> newFirefoxPids = pidsAfter.Except(pidsBefore);
        foreach (int pid in newFirefoxPids)
        {
            Program.newBrowserPid=pid;
   //I could kill all open instances here but I dont want to
        }
        driver.SwitchTo();
```

I could close down the existing FF instances or ask the user if they wish to close their browsers, though this is not ideal.

Comment: I find this approach inherently flawed. There is no real way to detect whether a browser instance is launched by Selenium or by a user. Why are you trying to do this, is there a particular reason? When you get that error, what's open? How many browser instances? How many did Selenium open by that point? How many did you open?

Comment: I have no browser open at all.  I launch selenium to open a browser WITh the user profile, I then open manually another browser again with the user profile, I then launch selenium to try to USE the current browser and it complains about the lock.

Comment: Another situation.  A single browser is open using the default profile, I try to launch selenium to use the default profile and it complains about the lock, I then kill the instance running, re attempt to open the browser and profile and it works.  I am able to get the PID so i can then add tabs to the current browser instead of launching a new browser, it works fine, I can use sendkeys to open multiple tabs on the browser.  I then open another browser manually start it up - then try to open with selemium a new tab on the first browser and it complains about the parent.lock.

Answer (score -1):

Creating of a copy of the default profile then pointing your selenium to this copied profile is one way around the issue. This way you don't have to kill other FF processes.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\CopyOfProfile");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

If you needed it to stay up to date with the original profile, you could monitor the original directory and replicate changes to the copy, or just run a scheduled task that recopies periodically. Depending on what you are automating, keeping it up-to-date may be completely unnecessary.