# Error in creating an instance of Firefox using selenium 2.48.0

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using **Selenium 2.48.0.0** on Firefox version 31.0. but whenever I create a instance of firefox by using

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

It gives me the following error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous.ef588110f81d4fd781e5aa75622d3f98.webdriver-profile.staging\webdriver.xpi\components\bad-cert-listener.js'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Any particular reason to use old versions of both Selenium & Firefox?

Comment: I have tried the latest ver too but the error remains the same..

Comment: Latest ver of what? Selenium or Firefox or both?

Comment: You can try to create a new profile, if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/35688624/2224701

Comment: are you trying for any secure site like https or something like intrusted ssl site.?

Comment: Selenium 2.53.0 with firefox 47.0b7

Comment: for checking purposes i am trying to access facebook.com

Comment: Try something like this `driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), firefoxProfile, pageLoadTimeout);`